# How to burn two ISO files on a same DVD disc?

Tags: cd-rom, dvd-burning

I have an old 1st-person shooter game for Windows which is split into two ISO files each with a little more than 600 MB. Those files are meant to burn two CD installation discs. I would thus run the installer (on the 1st CD) which would demand the insertion of the 2nd CD when appropriate (that is, when the installer is finished with the 1st CD). Not a big problem, but I was wondering if I couldn't burn *both* ISO files into a single DVD disc - so that the installation goes (hopefully) without interruption to replace media. That would make the whole operation easier, faster and more reliable (less room for media errors), I guess.

I have two burners: CDBurnerXP and WinX DVD Ripper Platinum. I tried to burn a DVD from those two ISO files sequentially. That didn't work, obviously. What should I do? Burn the first ISO, leave the DVD open for further recording and then burn the 2nd ISO? Or should I combine the contents of the two CDs burnt with the two ISOs into one single DVD?